# Web - can't open index page

Tags: apache, redirect, web, indexing

i'm having a prob. I've just made up a website in EasyPHP, everything runs ok on localhost. Problem came out after that i uploaded files on VPS to webserver, also the same prob. on webhosting. I cannot open my index.php file, everytime it redirects me to login.php - administration. Without index.php or login.php web doesn't work at all. The content of index file is simple, just couple php script to show content, function to query SQL... no redirection. thnks for help

Comment: It is impossible for anyone to answer this. We cannot _guess_ what script you uploaded, what hosting provider you use, what package you bought. In short: add more details to the question by editing it. There is an `edit` button above for this.

Comment: Can you post the code of your index file?

Answer (score 0):

The index.php is supposed to be the default file if you access your website without pointing to any specific file. May be you can try by removing login.php (or rename it to login.php.whatever) and access your website and see whether index.php is invoked. If it works, then probably some configuration in Apache (or your webserver) needs to be changed to look for index.php etc.

Hope this helps.